# Render view/template accessible by 2 different users

Tags: django

I'm working with my friend on a Django application and we get an issue with our website.

**In order to resume :**

We have an Admin user which can access to each part from our website.
Our application manages contracts for different companies. Each compagny can access to their homepage and consult interventions, points balance, ...

Each compagny have a user account to connect in our website.

To access to their homepage after the log process, I wrote in the `log application`:

```
def connexion(request):
    error = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ConnexionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  
            if user.username == 'Admin':  
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accueil'))
            elif user.username == 'Compagny1':  
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('http://localhost:8000/Compagny/1/')
            elif user.username == 'Compagny2':  
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('http://localhost:8000/Compagny/2/')
            else : 
                error = True
    else:
        form = ConnexionForm()

    return render(request, 'connexion.html', locals())
```

Then, `Compagny model` looks like :

```
class Compagny(models.Model):

    Nom = models.CharField(null= False, max_length=70, verbose_name='Nom de Société')
    ...
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=" ")
```

The url which let to go to the `Homepage` is :

```
url(r'^Compagny/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.Homepage, name="Homepage"),
```

Finally, in my view, I have :

```
@login_required
def Homepage(request, id) :

    compagny = get_object_or_404(Compagny, pk=id, user=request.user)
    ...
    # form part


        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://localhost:8000/Compagny/'+id)
    ...
    return render(request, 'Homepage.html', context)
```

I have 2 questions about my process :

- How I can set two `user_id` for one compagny (`Admin` and `compagny_user`) ?
- There is an other way which could `redirect compagny_user` to each compagny homepage better than my script part ?

Comment: I think your friend [asked this question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45006792/1324033), the response on that question is what trouble are you having with using the users id? how can you set 2 id's would be too broad, you should stick to 1 question per question

Comment: Oh I didn't know ... I assigned to a compagny a `user_id` thanks to @Alasdair in my previous question. But if I define the `homepage compagny` accessible by `user_id compagny`, I can't overcome to this page as Admin user. How I can define Admin permissions in order to access to each homepage :/

Answer (score 1):

First question: I think is better to point from user to Compagny. Then, you can have many users pointing to the same company. But, if you want, you can change to a many2many relationship. Change your Compagny model:

```
class Compagny(models.Model):

    Nom = models.CharField(null= False, max_length=70, verbose_name='Nom de Société')
    ...
    ...
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.username)
```

Second question: You can create a dictionary with users as keys and companys as values. For example:

```
AUTH_USER_COMPANY = {
    'user1': 1,
    'user2': 1,
    'user3': 2,
   ...
   }
```

. Then `HttpResponseRedirect("/Compagny/"+ str(settings.AUTH_USER_COMPANY[settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL]))`

It seems like you need to extend the user model.

Comment: The first part works very well ! According to the second one, you wrote : `Create a modelfield in the user model pointing to the company id`.How I can add a new model field if my user table is : `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`

Comment: Yes!. I was wrong. I will update my answer with something according to your problem.

Comment: I added the dictionary : `AUTH_USER_COMPANY = {
    'Admin': 1,
    'visiteur': 1,
    'visiteur2': 2,}` in my settings.py file. Then I have in my log views : `if user :
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('http://localhost:8000/Compagny/' + str(settings.AUTH_USER_COMPANY[settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL]))
` But I have an issue  : `Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
u'auth.User'`

Comment: I dont know your AUTH_USER_MODEL,  maybe you need to pass `str(settings.AUTH_USER_COMPANY[settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.username])` ??